How to Remove Wildcard Imports from a Large Python Repository?
I am working on a large python project that contains many thousands of files, includes a mix of independent scripts (many with main functions) and common modules.
Unfortunately, in my project there is extense usage of wildcard imports (e.g., from module import *).
This causes me to not be able to do automatic optimize for unused imports.
My goal is to replace these wildcard imports with explicit imports, but every time I start, I encounter hundreds of unresolved reference errors all over my project. I am looking for a systematic approach to tackle this task efficiently.
The codebase is quite large, making manual resolution impractical.
Has anyone here ever encountered and solved such a frustrating task?
Where Should I Start?

it seems hard task. It would know what functions and classes was used from module to put them in place of * or to add them prefix module. The only idea: grep module from file, run import module and use dir(module) to see what functions and classes are in this module - and later search these elements in source code - and put them in place of * or add prefix module.

Are you trying to get to from module import a, b, c, or are you trying to get to import module and using module.a, module.b, and module.c in your code?

Either approach works for me. I'm looking for the safest and fastest solution to implement.

I think the astroid library is a good place to start. This solution isn't going to be complete because some of the details will depend on your environment and the project, but it's a starting point.
Essentially, the following script parses a module into an AST, which it then analyzes to find the origin of all locals. It gathers a dictionary that maps import nodes to names that were imported using a "from" import. Once the mapping is complete, it replaces those import nodes with explicit imports.
You asked where you should start, and this is just a starting point; there is still a lot of room for improvement. Here are a few points for improvement that come to mind.

The output of the script will include unused imports, but there are plenty of tools already available for eliminating unused imports.
You may need to make some improvements for handling relative imports.
I haven't tested the case where a name in the module shadows/hides an imported name.

main.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import astroid
import sys
import pathlib

def main():
    source_path = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[1])
    source = source_path.read_text()
    module = astroid.parse(source)
    replacements = {}
    for local in module.locals:
        mod, nodes = module.scope_lookup(module, local)
        for node in nodes:
            if isinstance(node, astroid.ImportFrom):
                if node in replacements:
                    replacements[node].append(local)
                else:
                    replacements[node] = [local]
    lines = source.split('\n')
    for node, locals in replacements.items():
        lines[node.lineno - 1] = f'from {node.modname} import {", ".join(locals)}'

    print('\n'.join(lines))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

sample.py:
import platform
from pathlib import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello, world!')

Example output:
> ./main.py sample.py

import platform
from pathlib import fnmatch, functools, io, ntpath, os, posixpath, re, sys, warnings, PurePath, PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath, Path, PosixPath, WindowsPath, Sequence, EINVAL, ENOENT, ENOTDIR, EBADF, ELOOP, attrgetter, S_ISDIR, S_ISLNK, S_ISREG, S_ISSOCK, S_ISBLK, S_ISCHR, S_ISFIFO, urlquote_from_bytes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello, world!')

